# How to run multiple websites from single WordPress setup

Tags: php, htaccess

I want to create a website like visahq.com in WordPress, actually visahq.com has multiple websites like visahq.in for India, visahq.ru(will be shown in Russian) for Russia etc. and each TLD has multiple sub-domains like visahq.in has a sub-domain for Australia http://australia.visahq.in/ like on for each country. Content of all websites are almost same with some changes based on conditions.

My problem is I want to manage all TLD and sub-domains on a single WordPress setup how can I do this with WordPress.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set up a [multisite installation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) with [sunrise configuration](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-multisite-domain-mapping-tutorial/). This would allow you to manage one installation for your multiple domains.

Be sure your hosting is ready for it.

Answer (score 7):

The answers from JMa & brasofilo are perfectly valid.

But as you state that your question is about internationalization & that the content of the pages will be almost similiar, you may be better of with another solution. It can be quite a nightmare to sync a lot of content between wp multisites.

You should also read the [Before You Create A Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network) page of the Codex. Particularly the "Do you really need a network?" part.

> If you plan on creating sites that are strongly interconnected, that
>   share data, or share users, then a multisite network might not be the
>   best solution.

If your websites will have almost identical content and just a few static pages per website are different, you can have a look at the [Domain Mapping System](http://wordpress.org/plugins/domain-mapping-system/) plugin. That plugin is able to map domains to static pages.

If you need internationalization on top of this, you might just additionally install [qTranslate](http://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate/) or [WPML](http://wpml.org/).

**To sum up:**

- If your websites will differ only by theme (layout/menu) and one (or only a few) custom static-pages then you should have a look at the DMS plugin.
- If you want the websites to act like separate wordpress installs use wp multisite.

You could also use a mixture of both solution e.g. multisites with each site having the DMS plugin enabled so *visahq.in* is a multisite blog and *australia.visahq.in* is a DMS mapped static page within that multisite blog.

This are just a few hints from me. I think the desired system is way to complex and we don't have the full specification context here to provide a direct solution, but just to show up some possible ways and give some ideas.

Answer (score 3):

You need to [setup WordPress as a Multisite network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) and use the plugin [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/).

> Map any blog/site on a WordPressMU or WordPress 3.X network to an external domain.

The WPMS installation has to be done as "Sub-domains". And your server needs a "Wildcard Sub-domain" entry, so new subsites can be added easily from the Dashboard.

After that, park the TLD in cPanel (or similar) pointing to your `public_html` folder (the one used by WP) and, using the plugin, add a new mapping and mark the TLD as "primary".
So what was `http://subsite.example.com` starts to work as `http://custom-tld.com`.

Using another plugin like [Multilingual Press](http://wordpress.org/plugins/multilingual-press/), the site `http://australia.custom-tld.com`, created manually in cPanel and pointing to `public_html`, can be mapped to another sub-site of the network.

***Relevant ebooks: [WordPress Multisite 101](http://halfelf.org/ebooks/wordpress-multisite-101/) and [WordPress Multisite 110](http://halfelf.org/ebooks/wordpress-multisite-110/).***

Answer (score 3):

I dig all the current answers. For you specifically, I especially like @s1lv3r's answer in taking a step back and making sure you really need a multisite installation. Don't get hung up on one idea, like each language having its own TLD.

That said, I'd like to throw another option into the ring for others who come along looking for a way to **run multiple sites in one WordPress installation, with some sites having their own subdomains**.

The way WordPress' infrastructure is built, there are **networks** and **sites**, with a one-to-many relationship between networks and sites. A typical multisite install is one network with many sites. It's actually possible to have multiple networks, each with many sites. While the ability is there, WordPress doesn't provide a UI for it. There are a couple of plugins to provide that UI, like [WP Multi Network](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-network/). With this setup, each network would have its own domain, like foo.com and bar.com. Each network can then have unlimited subdomains, like sub1.foo.com, sub2.foo.com, sub1.bar.com, sub3.bar.com, and so on.